# Proving $f:[a,b) \longrightarrow (a,b)$ cannot be bijective and continuous (verification)

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification

I have come up with a proof for the expression, which I am confident in, but if there is anything wrong with it, please do let me know where exactly I went wrong and what incorrect assumption was made; I would like to be able to come up with the solution on my own. Thank you!

Assume $f:[a,b) \longrightarrow (a,b)$ is both continuous and bijective. By the bijectivity of $f$, there exists one, and only one $x \in [a,b)$ such that $f(x) = y \in (a,b)$. As such, let $f(a) \in (a,b)$. Moreover, let $U \subset (a,b)$ be an open neighborhood of $f(a)$. Now, by continuity of $f$ at $0$, there exists some $V \in [a,b)$ open such that $a \in V$ and $f(V) \subset U$. However, $V$ cannot be open since for any $r > 0$, $B_r(a) \not\subset V \implies f$ is not continuous. We conclude that $f$ cannot be bijective and continuous.

*The intervals are regarded with the subset topology induced by the standard topology of $\mathbb R$*

Comment: hint (if you've talked about connectedness):  if you remove a point from $(a,b)$, it's disconnected

Comment: Notice you want $V$ to be open in $[a,b)$ with the subspace topology, hence $V=[a,b) \cap U$ with $U$ some open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let $f(a) = c$. Now, remove c from (a,b) and consider the restriction map on $f$, namely $$g:(a,b) \longrightarrow (a,c) \cup (c,b)$$ The image of this function is the union of two connected intervals. Since $(a,b)$ is connected, its image must also be connected meaning it is wholly contained in either $(a,c)$ or $(c,b)$ but not both. As such, the image of the original function, $f$, is a proper subset of $(a,b)$ contradicting the bijectivity of $f$. @yoyo

Comment: Yes, this is the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Hint) The definition of (open) ball:
$$
B_r(c) =\{x \in [a,b)~|~d(x,c) < r \}
$$
where $d$ is a metric given that $[a,c)$ is a metric space. That is, it is always true that
$$
B_r(c) \subseteq [a,h)
$$
for all $r >0 $ and all $c \in [a,c)$ where $h \in (a,c)$.